# Best way to expose a Function App in a UI (swagger-like) for testing?

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I am about to delivery a serveless API in Function App, with 5 functions, and my client needs some sort of interactive documentation with the testing environment. They accept Swagger and graphql endpoints, but I insisted on pursuing the servelss aproach, so now I'm stuck with this quick problem. Should I simply make a swagger-like wrapper application? Is there any known framework that documents and exposes Function Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a wrapper application, the official recommendation is to pair Azure Functions with Azure API Management (which also has a consumption-based plan) to [expose your functions with a swagger definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition).

Along with now having a swagger definition, Azure APIM provides lots of functionality like rate limiting, authentication, caching etc. which you can read more about in the [official APIM docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts).